# how to add mongodb.so to AMPPs

Tags: mongodb, php.ini, composer, ampps

I want to use MongoDB in my laravel project, when I'm trying to add mongoDB driver to composer I get :

```
  Problem 1
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb (locked at 1.0.3) -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.3].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /usr/local/ampps/php-5.6/etc/php.ini
    - /usr/local/ampps/php-5.6/etc/php.d/20-mongo.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I'm using AMPPS 3.5 for running and building my projects and it has MongoDB preinstalled.

when I searched it's files under php5.6 in extension directory there is `mongo.so` and what i need is `mongodb.so`.

How can i fix this error and make MongoDB driver works on AMPPS

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, just install AMPPS version 3.6 which by default has mongodb, and configure it to work with laravel (enable needed extention) Then if you run this command in terminal `composer require jenssegers/mongodb`
it will download required package.